# How does Ethereum BLS signature verification works?

Tags: cryptocurrency, bls-signature

I am implementing BLS signature verification on smart contracts and I have a question regarding the way that Ethereum verifies the signature. Recall that bls signature works as

- $e(P_2,H(m)_1)_T=e(G_2, S_1)_T$ where $_2$ and $_1$ denote points of $G_2$ and $G_1$, and $_T$ for $G_T$.
- Off-chain, you take your secret $x$ , and do $x\,G_2\to P_2$ (your public key).
- You then provide your public key $P_2$ to the on-chain contract.
- You then generate your signature, $x\,H(m)_1\to S_1$.
- You provide signature to on-chain contract.
- It verifies $e(P_2,H(m)_1)_T=e(G_2, S_1)_T$.

However, Ethereum verifies the equality little differently than the last line. Specifically they check if:

$$e(A_2,B_1)*e(C_2,D_1)==1_T$$

The pseudo-code that does all this can be written by

```
from py_ecc.bn128 import *
p = curve_order
x = randint(1, p-1) # out secret key
H_m = multiply(G1, randint(1, p-1)) # lets pretend it's HashToPoint
P = multiply(G2, x) # our public key in G2
S = multiply(H_m, x) # our signature in G1
a = pairing(P, H_m)
b = pairing(G2, S)
assert a == b # Verify signature
```

To use equivalent of `ECPAIRING`, you’d then do:

```
c = pairing(G2, neg(S))
assert a * c == FQ12.one()
```

What I don't understand is how $e(A_2,B_1)*e(C_2,D_1)==1_T$. I far as I know the `neg` stands for negation operation. The `ECPAIRING` is the opcode they named. Can someone help me to see what I am missing?

<sup>Moderator's note: some of this question matches [that post](https://ethresear.ch/t/precompiled-snark-pairing-for-bls-signatures/3196/5)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all comes down to the properties of the pairing operation (commonly denoted as $e$, called `pairing` in the code).

$e$ is a function that takes two elliptic curve points as inputs, and generates a value for which multiplication and exponentiation makes sense (in practice, it is an element within an 'extension field', however you don't need to worry what that means)

One property that $e$ has is this identity:

$$e(aG, bH) = e(G,H)^{ab}$$

This identity is true for any integers $a, b$, and any two points $G, H$.

The BLS signature verification logic relies on this: if the public key is $P_2 = xG_2$ (and $G_2$ is also known by the verifier), and the message is mapped to a point $H(m)_1$, and the signature is $S_1 = xH(m)_1$, then the standard BLS verify (assuming a valid signature) computes the two pairings:

$$e(P_2, H(m)_1) = e(xG_2, H(m)_1) = e(G_2, H(m)_1)^x$$

$$e(G_2, S_1) = e(G_2, xH(m)_1) = e(G_2, H(m)_1)^x$$

If the signature is invalid, the second equation evaluates to something else.

If $S_1$ is in fact $xH(m)_1$ (that is, if the signature is valid, these two values are the same.

Now, the Ethereum BLS verification logic is equivalent, but works slightly differently: it instead computes (again, if the signature is valid):

$$e(G_2, -S_1) = e(G_2, -xH(m)_1) = e(G_2, H(m)_1)^{-x}$$

Remember, negating a point is the same as multiplying it by -1.

And again, if the signature is invalid, it evaluates to something else.

And so, if the signature is valid, the verifier has just computed the two values $e(G_2, H(m)_1)^x$ and $e(G_2, H(m)_1)^{-x}$; these are multiplicative inverses of each other, and so multiplying them together evaluates to one.

Comment: This was great explanation. Thank you!